# What is the Content-Type when injecting an operation directly to the node

Tags: node, api

I am attempting to inject a binary/signed operation with this command:

curl -v localhost:8732//injection/operation?chain=main --data "49EB87C4611C8E3471DAC13A8F1E6B9B73FD322A8499ABE6D3F9BCBCBD3EEDE96C00A7A663F3F59716611FBE11F298692599CCA2C177D08603F4E18003D84F00A08D060000C922032394F35A2397C78DB8A01A6BC8EADAB6ED007B993961FF5E65CB2F433363558CD94B6FE78F9E9E056C7E4F7F6AD8561C5CF50EAAD6CF81451CAA36312429243B19102E06E92A278523AB1BE637AEAD0AD509"

I get an error "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type" but I cannot find any information on what Content-Type to use in this post.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it is application/octet-stream - found that just after posting

Comment: This issue now is how to determine what the parsing error is.  The node returns "Failed to parse the request body: Failed to parse binary data" and I don't see anything in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 media types the node understands are `"application/json"`, `"application/bson"` and `"application/octet-stream"`. Of course, the body has to be coherent (and therefore differs) with the media type you chose.

`"49EB87C4611C8..."` is indeed some `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: It seems to work when we submit like this:
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" "localhost:8732//injection/operation?chain=main" --data <singlequote><doublequote>......<doublequote><singlequote>